# Designing Go programs to avoid circular dependencies

Tags: go

I am new in Golang and I make an example for learning it but I am facing import cycle not allowed into my example so anyone know how to avoid this? Here is my code.

Bank,go

```
package Bank

import (
    "../../class/human"
    "fmt"
)

func Transfer(payer, receiver *human.Human, payment float64) {
    if payer.Bank > payment {
        payer.Bank -= payment
        receiver.Bank += payment
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Bank balance not enough")
    }
}
```

Human.go

```
package human

// import "../../func/Bank"

type Human struct {
    Name string
    Cash float64
    Bank float64
}

func (h *Human) Transfer(Receiver Human, payment float64) {

}
```

Main.go

```
package main

import (
    "./class/human"
    "./func/Bank"
)

func main() {
    gary := human.Human{"Gary", 2000.0, 40000.0}
    Sam := human.Human{"Sam", 10000.0, 500000.0}

    Bank.Transfer(&Sam, &gary, 5000)

}
```

In above code is work fine with

```
Bank.Transfer(&Sam, &gary, 5000)
```

But I think it should be Human use the Bank function so how can i re-write it into this?

```
Sam.Transfer(&gary, 5000)
```

I have tried to import Bank.go in Human.go but got the import cycle not allowed  error. 
I am not sure is that my logical mistake or my bad code design but let see if someone can have a solution on this.

**Updated Content below**

After reading the message, i still don't understand how to implement Interface in this scenario. However, i did changed my code, please take a look to see if it is much better in code design for golang or it still the same? Thank you.

```
package main

// Human.go
type Human struct {
    Name string
    Cash float64
    Bank float64
}

// Bank.go
type Bank struct {
    Acct *Human
}

func (b *Bank) Transfer(receiver *Human, payment float64) {
    payer := b.Acct
    payer.Bank -= payment
    receiver.Bank += payment
}

// main.go
func main() {
    gary := Human{"Gary", 2000.0, 40000.0}
    Sam := Human{"Sam", 10000.0, 500000.0}

    Sam_Account := Bank{&Sam}

    Sam_Account.Transfer(&gary, 5000)

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you should *not* be using relative imports in Go `../../whatever` - Use the full path `github.com/your/project/where/is/your/code` - Read up on the `$GOPATH` . Go 1.11 Modules will help with *where* your code is, but the import path is still very important.

Comment: The fact that you've organized your code into `class` and `func` shows you may have a background in OOP, and you may be carrying some of that over to Go, which will cause some frustration in the long run. You definitely want to stop thinking about "classes" now, early in your Go learning, it will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Golang and Stack Overflow!

This seems to be a general software engineering question on how to design the data structures and operations in your project and their dependencies.

As you've discovered, circular imports are bad. There are many ways of changing the design to decouple things. One is clear layers - for example, `Bank` should probably depend on `Human` but not the other way around. However, if you want to provide convenient functionality to transfer money from `Human` to `Human`, one thing you could do is define an interface that a `Bank` object will implement.

For simplicity, however, I'd recommend strict layering. There's no real reason a `Human` should depend on a `Bank`. In the limit this can end up too cumbersome, since `Human`s need more services (would you make a `Human` depend on a `Bus` to make it possible for `Bus`es to move `Human`s around?)

---

To answer the comment and the updated question, I'd keep it simple:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Human struct {
    ID   int64
    Name string
}

type Account struct {
    ID int64

    // Note: floats aren't great for representing money as they can lose precision
    // in some cases. Keeping this for consistency with original.
    Cash float64

    DaysSinceActive int64
}

type Bank struct {
    Accounts map[int64]Account
}

// Not checking negatives, etc. Don't use this for real banking :-)
func (bank *Bank) Transfer(src int64, dest int64, sum float64) error {
    srcAcct, ok := bank.Accounts[src]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("source account %d not found", src)
    }
    destAcct, ok := bank.Accounts[dest]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("destination account %d not found", dest)
    }
    // bank.Accounts[src] fetches a copy of the struct, so we have to assign it
    // back after modifying it.
    srcAcct.Cash -= sum
    bank.Accounts[src] = srcAcct
    destAcct.Cash += sum
    bank.Accounts[dest] = destAcct
    return nil
}

func main() {
    gary := Human{19928, "Gary"}
    sam := Human{99555, "Sam"}

    bank := Bank{Accounts: map[int64]Account{}}
    bank.Accounts[gary.ID] = Account{gary.ID, 250.0, 10}
    bank.Accounts[sam.ID] = Account{sam.ID, 175.0, 5}

    fmt.Println("before transfer", bank)

    if err := bank.Transfer(gary.ID, sam.ID, 25.0); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("after transfer", bank)
}
```

This code uses loose coupling, as mentioned in my original answer. All the bank needs to know about a human is their ID (could be SSN or something calculated from the name, date of birth and other things) to identify them uniquely. Humans should hold banks (what if a person has accounts in multiple banks?). Banks shouldn't hold humans (what if accounts belong to multiple persons, corporations, virtual entities?) and so on. There's no need for interfaces here, and you can safely place each data type in their own package if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks for the answering but i still dont understand how to use Interface for this Cases. Would you mind to build an example for me? And i did updated my code above, if you have time, please check if it is good.

Comment: @garyc2232: I posted a code sketch in response to your comment and updated question